# List leaf directories in R

Tags: r

I have a directories tree structure like this:

```
.
|-Root
|---Folder1
|---Folder2
|------SubFolder1
|------SubFolder2
```

The folders may contain files, but I'm only interested in listing the leaf folders.

In the example above, what I'm looking for is:

```
Root/Folder1
Root/Folder2/SubFolder1
Root/Folder2/SubFolder2
```

I have tried with `list.dirs("Root", recursive = TRUE)`, but it returns:

```
Root
Root/Folder1
Root/Folder2
Root/Folder2/SubFolder1
Root/Folder2/SubFolder2
```

In real life, my directory structure is of course bigger than this example given as an illustration.

Comment: How is `unlist(lapply(list.dirs("Root", recursive = F),  list.dirs, recursive = T))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on other answers and comments, I came up with this:

```
folders <- list.dirs("Root")
folders <- folders[sapply(folders, function(x) length(list.dirs(x, recursive = FALSE)) == 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it should work :

```
getPathLeaves <- function(path){
  children <- list.dirs(path, recursive = FALSE)
  if(length(children) == 0)
    return(path)
  ret <- list()
  for(child in children){
    ret[[length(ret)+1]] <- getPathLeaves(child)
  }
  return(unlist(ret))
}
```

Usage :

```
getPathLeaves("Root")
```